# Bokeh - select country in interactive map

Tags: python, bokeh

I am creating an interactive world map with Bokeh (Bokeh server). The countries are represented by patches. Countries should be selectable by the Taptool. However, some countries consist of several patches. By clicking on one country patch, the entire country, i.e. all corresponding patches should appear as selected.
I can solve this by the following code. However, there is a visible time lag between the selection of the patch I click on, and the other patches that belong to this country. Therefore I wonder, is there a more efficient/easy way achieve this?

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Patches
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.io import curdoc
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models.selections import Selection

x = [[5,2,4], [3,5,6], [6,9,7], [8,7,6]]
y = [[5,3,2], [6,5,8], [3,1,6], [1,2,1]]
country = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B']
id = [0,1,2,3]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(x=x, y=y, country=country, id=id))
source = ColumnDataSource(df)

p = figure(tools="tap")
renderer = p.patches('x', 'y', source=source)

def my_tap_handler(attr,old,new):
    indices = source.selected.indices
    country_name = source.data['country'][indices[0]]
    country_indices = df['id'][df['country'] == country_name]
    if len(source.selected.indices) == 1:
        new_indices = list(country_indices)
        source.selected = Selection(indices=new_indices)

renderer.data_source.on_change("selected", my_tap_handler)
curdoc().add_root(row(p, width=800))
```

Run in terminal: `bokeh serve filename.py --show`

Comment: related to my previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50492995/bokeh-server-how-to-manipulate-a-selection-in-a-callback-function