# What are indices in Bokeh?

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh

`Indices` are an attribute of the class `Selection`.

[From the Bokeh Documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/selections.html#bokeh.models.selections.Selection.line_indices):

*"They represent all the indices included in a selection."*

`Selection` came from the module `bokeh.models` a group of "building block" classes.

[image]

I can't find in the documentation an exaustive  "indices" definition.

***What are indices?
How to use them in Bokeh?***

I supposed that should be considered like the `index` of `ColumnDataSource`, or a DataFrame, but I am not sure about that.

I am not sure because, [reading the documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/sources.html) `bokeh.models.sources`, `ColumnDataSource` doesn't have any `indices` parameters unlike `pandas.DataFrame`

The question raised after reading and studying [that question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50492995/bokeh-server-how-to-manipulate-a-selection-in-a-callback-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bokeh selection indices are sequences containing integer index values into the columns of a `ColumbnDataSource`. The represent which (if any) of the points drawn from a data source have been selected. For instance if we plot:

```
p.circle(x=[1,2,3,4,5], y=[10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
```

and then use a box selection tool to select just the left-most two points *(1, 10)* and *(2, 20)* on the plot, then the value of `source.selection` will be `[0, 1]`. Or if we select just the right-most point *(5, 50)* then the selection indices will be `[4]`, etc.